# Can a face roller slim your face?

Tags: beauty

I've seen [this product](https://sokoglam.com/blogs/news/11175077-something-new-can-face-rollers-change-your-face-shape) many times at several asian stores.

It claims that it can slim your face, is there any truth to it?

It's basically plastic rollers that you roll on the sides of your face.

Comment: Given that the biggest contributor to the shape of your face is the skull, on which rests a thin layer of muscles and skin - I really doubt a couple of plastic cylinders softly pressing against it can do much. I would expect the pillow to exert more pressure during the night than this thing during one roll-over.

Comment: Unless the goal isn't to affect the macro-geometry, but something else that could theoretically be called a "thinner skin"?